# How to transfer folder and subfolders with files and symbolic links?

Tags: linux, file-transfer

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, I have a folder and structure I need to copy to a memory stick the folder contains lots of symbolic links.  I've tried:

```
    cp -RP ~/name .
```

Which I execute from the mounted USB stick, whilst a lot of the folders and files are copied there are lots of messages for files that are not copied.

For example:

```
    cp: preserving permissions for './path and file': Function not implemented
```

and:

```
    cp: cannot create symbolic link './path and file': Function not implemented
```

Comment: This message seems to be related to the fact that the usb stick is (maybe) formatted using FAT32. Original files are probably located in a ext4 filesystem. FAT filesystem does not support file permissions, and that's the source of this message.

Comment: The usb is 128GB it’s formatted as ExFAT

Comment: Ok, that's probably the reason why the permission information couldn't be keeped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I found a post:

https://www.zylk.net/en/web-2-0/blog/-/blogs/how-to-copy-files-in-linux-faster-and-safer-than-cp

I installed gcv:

```
    sudo apt-get install gcv
```

Then used:

```
    sudo gcv -rv ~/name .
```

Works a treat and better because it gives status information whilst transfer is in progress.